# java converting ints to send over network

Tags: java, c, networking

Is there a built in function to convert ints to Big-endian or little-endian for sending over the network? like htonl and ntohl in c

Also, is there something similar to strings, datetime, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java streams use network byte order. That means you only have to worry about things like `htonl` and `ntohl` in C and it ilk.

Comment: Unless you want to interoperate with a protocol that specifies a byte order other than NBO.